# How do I unselect exclude check box from the product images in magento admin?

Tags: magento

I am importing images using Magmi. But when I see the images in admin exclude check box is automatically selected for all the images.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I uncheck this check box.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you pust - sign before the images they will exclude those images.
You need to put + sign before the image to not exclude.

```
image => +/mylocalimage.png
image => +http://somewhere/remoteimage.jpg
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Mangik I will try this and inform you. Thanks